# Use version attribute of package.json in one of it's script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to use the version attribute of my package.json in one of it's scripts to put the version in the name of the JS bundle (i prefer to use the version as a unique identifier instead of a hash).

**what i have:**

```
"build-js": "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 ] ] js/components/App.js -o js/bundle.js"
```

**what i need (*i know it doesn't parse, but you get the idea*):**

```
"build-js": "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 ] ] js/components/App.js -o js/bundle."+this.version+".js"
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
"build-js": "browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 ] ] js/components/App.js -o js/bundle.$npm_package_version.js"
```

See this video for more details: https://egghead.io/lessons/tools-use-custom-config-settings-in-your-npm-scripts

P.S. It's worth not putting your bundle in the same directory as your source, usually it goes into `dist/`, e.g. `dist/bundle.js`. This way if you are publishing to npm you can ignore the unbuilt source directory. Or you can just remove the `dist/` dir and rebuild, plus in the future you'll want other assets in dist as part of your build process.

Comment: Thank you, i'll follow your tip

Answer (score 9):

When you run an npm script, npm will set all the `package.json` fields as environment variables that you can use:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars

you can use the `npm_package_version` environment variable